# Can you enable debugging 'Just My Code' in a NodeJS application in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging

I've been debugging in VS Code in our NodeJS Application and am a bit frustrated I have to step through 'library code' as I debug our application.

Can you enable a setting to debug 'just my code'; I've used similar settings before in Visual Studio for C# debugging, leaving out the .NET framework etc?

In the context of Node, I'd expect node_modules to be stepped over when a debugging my application, only stepping through code outside this directory.

Comment: Thanks @starball, I've voted to close my question as it is a duplicate of that question. I've just tested the answer to the other question and got the desired effect!